# Adding related user fields to comment field

Tags: 9

I have a content type which has a field that prints post related comments.
My users have a couple of extra fields like name and last_name. Is there a possibility to add the first and last name of a user to a comment they've written, instead of just the username and profile picture?

```
function mysite_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if($node && $node->getType() == 'berichten'){
        $variables['user'] = User::load($node->getOwnerId());
 
        $variables['field_reacties'] = $node->field_reacties->view('full');

    }

}
```

This is how I currently receive the comments view and show it to the related post.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I can just receive user related fields from a comment by doing this `{{ comment.getOwner.field_naam.value }}`
took me a while to figure that out, but it's handy for custom templates! :D